# How to get Apple Music on iPod Touch 1G?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, ipod, apple-music

I own an iPod Touch 1G and I'd like to listen to my downloaded Apple Music tracks on it. However, I can't do that since "Apple Music songs cannot be copied onto an iPod" (That's the message it shows me when trying to copy them on there) and I can't enable Apple Music on an iPod Touch 1G.

Is there any way to get around that?

Comment: By get around you mean circumventing the digital rights management and what Apple might call "pirate" the music _(or at least violate the terms of service)_? I'm not judging, just wanting to be clear what you are seeking to do since the obvious answer is "No - this doesn't work with Apple's OS and tools"

Comment: @bmike I mean a legal way. If there's none, then I don't want to risk my Apple Music membership

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *legal* way of doing that. However, there is a number of various online and downloadable converters you can use to get a usable file from the original `.m4p` one.

To get the file, just go to `/Music/iTunes Media/Apple Music/yourSong.m4p`.

Then, open a converter and just let it work its magic.

***WARNING:*** This way is *illegal*, *violates Apple Music's TOS* and is not at all nice. Do it on your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

My sources tell me you need iOS 8.4 to get Apple Music on an iPod.

Can yours run that version by updating the device?

If so - you are totally legal. If not, try selling that and getting a used device that’s able to run iOS 8 or newer.

See 5th generation iPod / A6 chip like: http://iossupportmatrix.com/

Comment: the iPod 1G runs iOS 3.1 and its selling price would be far too low to even consider selling it

Comment: Keep it for the museum - here is some DRM free music to load on it http://bigozine2.com/roio/ @ProkopHanzl